# Dto property that references another entity through Many-To-One relationship?

Tags: nestjs, entity, typeorm, one-to-many, dto

I have 2 entities that are tied to each other through One-To-Many/Many-To-One relationship. For this example, let's call them User And Photo.

A User has many Photos and many Photos have one User

```
@Entity({ name: 'user' })
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar' })
  name: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Photo, photo => photo.user, { cascade: true, onDelete: 'CASCADE', onUpdate: 'CASCADE' })
  photos: Photo[];
}
```

```
@Entity({ name: 'photo' })
export class Photo {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar' })
  name: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.photos)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'userId', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
  user: User;
}
```

Now, in my controller, I have a body dto like this:

```
@Controller('general_path')
export class MyController {
  constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

  @Post('/sub_path')
  async addPhoto(@Body() body: PhotoDto): Promise<Photo> {
    return await this.myService.addPhoto(body);
  }
}
```

My question is:
How should my PhotoDto look like given the fact that when a post request is made, I want the post body to contain the name of the new photo and the id of the user it will be tied to?

```
export class PhotoDto {
  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  name: string;

  userId: string
}
```

More specifically, how do I specify, in the dto, that userId is an id that references another entity (bc of the Many-To-One relationship)?

Comment: Do you mean to get photos by userId? just join it with queryBuilder and use leftJoinAndSelect.

Comment: @HaiAlison I'm not refering to getting photos by userId. I want the body of the request to be validated by the PhotoDto. How do I tell, inside the PhotoDto, that userId is a string id that refers to another entity?

Comment: I don't know what you actually wanted, the PhotoDto provided userId then must be the User entity